# area of a flat torus of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $R>r>0$. We get a torus $T_0$ from the map

$F(u,v)=((R+r\cos u)\cos v, (R+r\cos u)\sin v, r\sin u)$.

Now define a new  metric tensor on $T_0$ by

$(x_u,x_u)=(x_v,x_v)=1, (x_u, x_v)=0$.

The torus has zero curvature.

The question is, how to find the area of this torus?

I think it is now $4\pi^2$, as the area form is 1.
However the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Why it is not correct?

Comment: The correct answer should be $4\pi^2Rr$. Do you know how to derive that?

Comment: Whether this is a correct answer depends on how the question is asked. Can you say about the original wording of the question?

Comment: The quesion is to find the area of the flat torus T_0 with the new inner product defined above. could you show me how to do it?

Comment: Essentially the area of the torus has nothing to do with the mapping $F$. We are asked to find the area of the square $[0,2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$ with the standard metric. Of course the answer would be $4\pi^2$.

Comment: But the answer says the area is $4\pi^2Rr$. I am looking at Exercise 5, 7.3 of Elementary differential geometry by Oneill

Comment: That's why I want the exact wording of the question. The answer doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: Could you look at Exercise 5, 7.3 of Elementary differential geometry by Oneill

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have the book and I cannot have it on the web.^^

Comment: Then what do you think of the correct answer?

Comment: Well, if you use the metric given by $F$ (not $T_0$) to find the area, then you should come up with something related to $R$ and $r$. But I am not sure if it is $4\pi^2 Rr$.